# Safari removes element when calling append jquery method

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-append

I encounter a very strange situation with safari while not with other browsers (FF, IE, Chrome).

My HTML code is something like this:

```
<table id="tblObjectChannel"></table>
```

And my script is something like this:

```
var item = '<tr style="border-bottom:solid 1px #666;" id="xxxccc"><input type="hidden" id="hfObjectID0" value="2323" /></tr>';            

$('#tblObjectChannel').append(item);
```

In browsers other than Safari it will return like this:

```
<tbody><tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);" id="xxxccc"><input id="hfObjectID0" value="2323" type="hidden"></tr></tbody>
```

But in Safari it returns like this:

```
<tbody><tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);" id="xxxccc"></tr></tbody>
```

So, the hidden element is thrown away I don't know where. Am I missing a hidden feature of .append() method here?

You can witness this yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/mrMXS/ 
please try that link with FF and then with Safari. Any clue would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is it just me or is jsFiddle broken in Safari? The code inside the code-boxes is not displayed correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting some `<td>` elements around your hidden field - it's not valid HTML without them.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/mdUeu/ - tested on Safari on MacOS X and it works as expected.

Comment: waaa.. how can I be so stupid, and I have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer :S thanks.